# Download a file from given URL and retry on connection errors

Tags: python, python-2.x, url, network-file-transfer

I wrote a script for Python 2.78 which is supposed to download and save a file from a given URL using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

In case that a connection to the server can be established and a valid response is received, the response (e.g. a HTML file) should be downloaded to hard disk.

If the server gives a bad HTTP response code (anything but 200) or no connection could be established at all, a revealing error message should be printed, giving the specific type of error (e.g. 'connection refused' or 'HTTP 400 response code'. In this case, the download attempt should be retried until a predefined maximum of download tries is exceeded.

The URL and other connection parameters such as connection timeout, read timeout, maximum download attempts etc. as well as the location and filename for downloading the file can be specified on top of the script within the `CONFIGURATION` section. There can also be found some example URLs which mock bad server behaviour (based on [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/)).

The script works for me as is. However, I get the impression that it is overly complicated and includes too much nesting of the function which reduces readability. Moreover, the two configuration dictionaries are passed through several functions which I have the impression is hard to follow. Any suggestions on how to improve this code in terms of readability, simplicity or good coding style is appreciated!

```
###########
# IMPORTS #
###########

# file system browsing
import glob, os

# http services / file downloading
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# sleeping
import time


###########
# CONFIGURATION #
###########

# get path from which the script is being run
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# useful test urls:
# http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd <- returns a valid HTTP 200 response that can be downloaded and saved as html
# http://httpbin.org/delay/n <- returns response after n sec of delay (to create a timeout)
# http://httpbin.org/status/404 <- returns a HTTP 404 response

# connection parameters
connectionParameters = {'url' : r'http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd',
                        'user' : 'user',
                        'password' : 'passwd',
                        'connectTimeout' : 10,
                        'readTimeout' : 5,
                        'maxAttempts' : 3,
                        'secondsBetweenAttempts' : 3}

# download parameters
downloadParameters = {'folder' : r'{0}'.format(path),
                      'filename' : 'downloadedFile.html'}


##################
# Functions #
##################

# create custom exception for the case that the maximum of download tries is exceeded
class MaxAttemptsException(requests.RequestException):
    pass

# clean up the folder with the downloaded files so that old ones are not checked again in case that the download fails
def cleanUpDownloadFolder(downloadParameters):

    print('cleaning up download folder: {0}\n'.format(downloadParameters['folder']))

    os.chdir(downloadParameters['folder'])
    [[os.remove(r'{0}\{1}'.format(downloadParameters['folder'], filename)) for filename in glob.glob(extension)] for extension in ['*.*']]

    return

def getResponseFromServer(connectionParameters, downloadParameters):

    try:
        response = requests.get(url=connectionParameters['url'], auth=HTTPBasicAuth(connectionParameters['user'], connectionParameters['password']), timeout=(connectionParameters['connectTimeout'], connectionParameters['readTimeout']), verify=True)

        success = checkHTTPresponseStatus(response, connectionParameters, downloadParameters)

        return success

    # if no HTTP response from server, catch connection error and return None response
    except requests.RequestException as e:

        print('There was an error while connecting to the server. Error message:')
        print('{0}\n'.format(e.message))

        success = False
        return success

def sleepBetweenAttempts(connectionParameters):
    print('Waiting {0} seconds before next try...\n'.format(connectionParameters['secondsBetweenAttempts']))
    time.sleep(connectionParameters['secondsBetweenAttempts'])
    return

def increaseAttempts(attempt):
    attempt += 1
    return attempt

def saveFile(response, downloadParameters):

    try:

        with open(os.path.join(downloadParameters['folder'], downloadParameters['filename']), 'wb') as outputFile:
            outputFile.write(response.content)

        success = True
        return success

    except EnvironmentError as e:

        print('The downloaded file could not be saved on disk.')
        print('{0}\n'.format(e))

        success = False
        return success

def checkHTTPresponseStatus(response, connectionParameters, downloadParameters):

    try:

        # raise exception if response is not OK
        response.raise_for_status()

        # if response is OK, download and save file to disk
        success = saveFile(response, downloadParameters)

        return success

    # if response is NOT OK, an exception is raised. catch HTTP error.
    except requests.HTTPError as e:

        print('Connection to server has been established but there was a HTTP error')
        print('{0}\n'.format(e.message))

        success = False
        return success

def retry(attempt, connectionParameters):

    # increase download attempt counter, then sleep and try again if any attempts left
    try:

        attempt = increaseAttempts(attempt)

        if attempt > connectionParameters['maxAttempts']:
            raise MaxAttemptsException('MaxAttemptsException: Failed {0} attempts to download the file. Exiting...'.format(connectionParameters['maxAttempts']))

        else:
            sleepBetweenAttempts(connectionParameters)

    except MaxAttemptsException as e:

        print('{0}\n'.format(e.message))
        exit()

    return attempt

def tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer(connectionParameters, downloadParameters):

    attempt = 1

    while True:

        print('Downloading xml file from {0}, attempt {1}/{2}\n'.format(connectionParameters['url'], attempt, connectionParameters['maxAttempts']))
        success = getResponseFromServer(connectionParameters, downloadParameters)

        if success:

            print('File has been successfully downloaded and saved at {0}\{1}.'.format(downloadParameters['folder'], downloadParameters['filename']))
            break

        else:

            # file could not be downloaded or saved, try again
            attempt = retry(attempt, connectionParameters)

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer(connectionParameters, downloadParameters)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's naming case is `snake_case` (makes sense, right?); you are writing your identifiers and functions is `camelCase`.

For example, this:

```
connectionParameters
```

becomes:

```
connection_parameters
```

And, as another example, this:

```
cleanUpDownloadFolder
```

becomes this:

```
cleanup_download_folder
```

However, for classes, the naming case is `PascalCase`, which you did perfectly well for `MaxAttemptsException`.

---

It is a good idea to put all your `import`s together, as you did under your `IMPORTS` section. However, there are two problems:

1. In the next section, you `import os` *again*.
2. The `import os` in the next section is not up in the `IMPORTS` section with the other `import`s.

Since you are already `import`ing `os` in the `IMPORTS` section, you should just completely remove this line from `CONFIGURATION`:

```
import os
```

---

You have some fairly long function names:

- `tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer`
- `cleanUpDownloadFolder`
- `checkHTTPresponseStatus`

You seem to have some unnecessary words in these names. I would change these to:

- `download_xml`
- `clean_downloads`
- `check_response`

You don't need to be so specific with `tryTo` and `Folder` and `Server`... since your program is all about those, these topics should just be implied in your function names.

---

When you call the method `sys.exit`:

```
exit()
```

You should be passing an exit/error code. The exit code describes how execution went to external programs in a single number.

Any non-zero number means that something went wrong. Therefore, for example, when you are `exit`ing from the program in `retry`, you should be passing a non-zero number to show that something went wrong.

---

This seems awfully unnecessary:

```
success = False
return success
```

Why are you creating a variable with an extremely simplistic value, and then having it returned from the function in the very next line?

Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to just do:

```
return False
```

---

The same sort-of goes to these lines:

```
success = checkHTTPresponseStatus(response, connectionParameters, downloadParameters)

return success
```

Why are you creating a brand new variable to only have it destroyed in the next line?

You should just merge the content of `success` straight to the return statement, like this:

```
return checkHTTPresponseStatus(response, connectionParameters, downloadParameters)
```

You do this in a few other spots, along with the above recommendation. You should fix those spots too.

---

Your function `checkHTTPresponseStatus` is not doing what it seems like it should be doing. The title tells me,

> Oh, hey! Me? Yeah, I check to make sure that the response status from
>   the server is a good one.

However, what it really is doing is this:

> Oh, hey! Me? Yeah, I save the response file to the disk.

This leads me to my next point.

---

Starting from the first function you call, `tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer`, all the other functions that are called in this one are just a chain of results.

What I mean is, the `success` variable in `tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer` is going to be the return value of `saveFile` unless an error occurred along the way; in that case it'd be false.

Why? Well (assuming no errors have occured),

- `checkHTTPresponseStatus` returns the return of `saveFile`
- `getResponseFromServer` returns the return of `checkHTTPresponseStatus`
- `tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer` uses the return of `getResponseFromServer`.

To fix this, I'd say that you have two options:

- Since these functions do so little, just group them into one function.
- Move all error catching to one function, but keep the others doing their job.

I personally would choose the first one, because if you were to string the error catching and returns from all these functions, you would literally be left with a single line.

---

Here is how I would write the beginning of `tryToDownloadXmlFileFromServer`:

```
def download_xml(connection_params, download_params):
    attempt = 1

    while True
        try:
            print('Downloading xml file from {0}, attempt {1}/{2}\n'.format(connectionParameters['url'], attempt, connectionParameters['maxAttempts']))

            response = requests.get(url=connectionParameters['url'], auth=HTTPBasicAuth(connectionParameters['user'], connectionParameters['password']), timeout=(connectionParameters['connectTimeout'], connectionParameters['readTimeout']), verify=True)
            response.raise_for_status()

            with open(os.path.join(downloadParameters['folder'], downloadParameters['filename']), 'wb') as outputFile:
                outputFile.write(response.content)
```

Then, you do the error catching that you were doing in the other functions:

```
except requests.RequestException as e: #from getResponseFromServer
    [error message]

except requests.HTTPError as e: #from checkHTTPresponseStatus
    [error message]

except EnvironmentError as e: #from saveFile
    [error message]

attempt = retry(attempt, connectionParameters)
```

Here is what is happening in the error message part:

1. If there were any errors from the code in the `try`, enter the respective `except`.
2. Once the `except` is finished, set the new attempt amount
3. Go back up the to the `while true` loop and try again.